# The default css of a td, centering automatically

Tags: html, css

What's the default css of a `td` which makes it so that stuff are automatically centered vertically?

I know how to get things to center horizontally given that a div is smaller than its parent with `margin: 0 auto` but what's allowing a td to center vertically automatically?

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#inner {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    centered only horizontally
  </div>
</div>

<table height=200 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      I center automatically
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default css of `td` elements is `display: table-cell`. This property, will also accept `vertical-align`.

So, you might need to set the css:

```css
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.outer {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table height="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>I am vertically centered</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    This is vertically centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you make a snippet demonstrating this?

Comment: I edit my post. Or, maybe your previous css overwrite the rule. It is not a good practice, but you might try to add `!important` rule after the `middle` in the `vertical-align`. So, it will be: `vertical-align: middle !important;`

Comment: Can you do it with a div inside another div, like my example? Pretty pointless to do it with a td since it's vertically centered by default.

Comment: I have added the example using div.

Answer (score 1):

```
 vertical-align: inherited;
```

for TD & TR in user agent stylesheet i.e default browser stylesheet. So TD is referring vertical-align of TBODY which is as below and thats causing it to align vertically in middle.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

To override, default stylesheet you can do something like

```
td{
 vertical-align: top !important ;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a snippet demonstrating this? Tried applying vertical-align and it didn't change anything. I'm pretty sure vertical-align is used in conjunction with `line-height`

Answer (score 0):

```
#outer{display:table-cell;}
#inner{vertical-align:middle;}
```